# How to add custom messages to Vim quicklist?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a file which contains code review comments by file and line numbers.

I'm writing a Vim plugin which uses Vim quicklist to display review comments when i open a file and navigate to the line number.

I've figured out that i can use `:cex` command to add entries to quicklist from [this documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)

How do i add error message in a format like `[file]:[line] [issue category][issue description]` which allows me to jump to that location?

Comment: A little bit further down in that page you can [find what you are looking for](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#error-file-format).

Comment: did you check errorformat?

Comment: The question was on how to use errorformat to get this working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help of `:cexpr` also provides the hint:

> ```
>       If {expr} is a String, then each new-line terminated
>       line in the String is processed using the global value
>       of 'errorformat' and the result is added to the
>       quickfix list.
> ```

```
:caddexpr printf('%s:%d:%s', expand('%'), line('.'), "entry")
```

Since the value of `'errorformat'` is difficult and may not be completely under your control (ftplugins may change it), an alternative is to directly set / append items via the `setqflist()` Vimscript function:

```
:call setqflist([{'bufnr': bufnr(''), 'lnum': 42, 'text': 'entry'}], 'a')
```